# htacess обрезать все символы после html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Для страниц товаров выводится страница с html.
Нужен редирект со страниц типа `сайт.ру/товар1.html/` и `сайт.ру/товар1.html?` на основную `сайт.ру/товар1.html`.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
# если в запросе есть подстрока .html
# и после нее идет символ / или ?
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html[/\?]
# то взять из адреса только подстроку от начала до .html включительно
# и перейти к этой странице с удалением get-параметров
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html) http://сайт.ру/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо! помогло